# I have error with .getText

Tags: listview

I want to click on listview and then show text but it have error .getText

```
   ListView listView = getListView();
   listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).findViewById(R.id.line_a).getText(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


              });
```

}

Comment: What error do you have? What is `R.id.line_a`?

Comment: R.id.line_a is list line that I want to show text

Comment: Trying to be a mentalist: `findViewById` returns a `null` object because of invalid input and then `getText()` on a `null` object returns NPE...BTW: the method ``findViewById` presumably needs to be fed by an `id` to work. So why don't you try passing as an argument `R.id` instead of `R.id.line_a`?